# Saving Workbook Files Created from VBA to Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am trying to use the code below to save Workbook files that are created from individual sheets in a secondary workbook into my department's SharePoint, but the files are not showing up after the macro has run. There are no errors showing up and when I tried running this macro in a folder on my desktop it saved all the files correctly. Any ideas as to why it just won't work when its in a SharePoint?

```
Sub SaveShtsAsBook()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet, SheetName$, MyFilePath$, N&
Dim theFilePath As String
MyFilePath$ = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    SheetName$ = Sheet.Name
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
         '      End With
        On Error Resume Next '<< a folder exists
        theFilePath = MyFilePath & "FY 20-21 P Card Statements - " & SheetName
        MkDir theFilePath
        theFilePath = theFilePath & "/" & "February Statement 1.6.21-2.6.21"
        MkDir theFilePath
        With Sheet
            .Select
            .Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=theFilePath & "/" & SheetName & " Feb-06.xlsx", FileFormat _
                :=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End With
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With
Next Sheet
End Sub
```